# vue3 setup - how to access ref element in click event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I use vue3 composition API and `<script setup>` .

```html
<textarea v-model="textarea"></textarea>
<button @click="showPreview">click</button>
<p ref="p" v-if="open"></p>
```

```js
const textarea = ref("");
const p = ref(null);
const open = ref(false);

function showPreview() {
  let text = textarea.value.replaceAll(/\n/g, "<br>");
  if (p.value) { // p is null
    p.value.innerHTML = text;
  }

  open.value = true;
}
```

I want to show textarea's text in `p` tag(not using `v-html`) when click button.

But `p` is null in function...

I tried check p variable in onMounted function but it still null.

```js
onMounted(() => console.dir(p))
```

How can I access ref element when **click event**?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `v-show` so that the element is in the DOM even when not displayed. With `v-if`, the `<p>` element is not rendered when `open` is false, so the ref is `null`.

```
<p ref="p" v-show="open"></p>
```

However, you should consider using a `ref` to store the text to display instead of working with the actual HTML elements. You can use the `<pre>` element to preserve whitespace without needing to replace linebreaks with `<br>`.

```
<template>
    <textarea v-model="textarea"></textarea>
    <button @click="showPreview">click</button>
    <pre v-if="result">{{result}}</pre>
</template>
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue';
const textarea = ref("");
const result = ref("");
function showPreview() {
  result.value = textarea.value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is safer than my answer ... 1+

Answer (score 0):

One way to display "raw" HTML is to use the `v-html` directive as per the [Vue site](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#text-interpolation).

For example:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const textarea = ref("");
const p = ref(null);
const open = ref(false);
const textToDisplay = ref ("");
  
const showPreview = () => {
  textToDisplay.value = textarea.value.replaceAll(/\n/g, "<br>");
  open.value = true;
}
</script>

<template>
    <textarea v-model="textarea"></textarea>
    <button @click="showPreview">click</button>
    <p v-if="open"><span v-html="textToDisplay"></span></p>
</template>
```

But be sure to use this with care and to sanitize any data being displayed in this fashion as per this warning about [Cross-Site Scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting):

[image]